# Rails - Capistrano deployment failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'm trying to figure out why a deployment is failing but can't see anything in the logs:

```
* 2017-12-04 11:54:56 executing `staging'
triggering start callbacks for `deploy'
* 2017-12-04 11:54:56 executing `multistage:ensure'
* 2017-12-04 11:54:56 executing `deploy'
triggering before callbacks for `deploy'
* 2017-12-04 11:54:56 executing `slack:starting'
* 2017-12-04 11:54:59 executing `deploy:update'
** transaction: start
* 2017-12-04 11:54:59 executing `deploy:update_code'
updating the cached checkout on all servers
* executing "if [ -d /home/rails/apps/premium-
tours/staging/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/rails/apps/premium-tours/staging/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 6bc353816fce7aa0b70ac97c3e46f79ee6ced659 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b staging git@github.com:rawnet/premium-tours /home/rails/apps/premium-tours/staging/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/rails/apps/premium-tours/staging/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 6bc353816fce7aa0b70ac97c3e46f79ee6ced659; fi"
servers: ["94.236.126.220"]
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing "rm -rf /home/rails/apps/premium-tours/staging/releases/20171204115614; true"

 servers: ["94.236.126.220"]
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: 94.236.126.220 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) for "94.236.126.220" port 22)
connection failed for: 94.236.126.220 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) for "94.236.126.220" port 22)
```

Any help is appreciated - like I say I don't know what to look for and can't see any error messages before it starts rolling back

Comment: The error is (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out). Capistrano can't connect to your server. Are you able to connect to it over ssh?

Comment: your git `HEAD` points to the top of the current branch?

Comment: I can connect to it via SSH (only after SSH'ing from another server thats been whitelisted) - and yup HEAD is pointing at the top

Answer (score 0):

Its connection issue, check the ip and port.
Try this:

## config/deploy/production.rb

server "#{server_ip_here}", user: "deploy", roles: %w{web app db}, port: 222

Comment: It all seems to be setup properly.... it can connect to the server in the first instance - if I try with a wrong password then I get a different error message